# Meteor.call won't work after build

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, meteor, build

I have a very strange problem with my meteor app that I can not figure out. I am using Meteor v1.3 and NodeJS v0.10.42. I am simply trying to take the text of an HTML form and email the data. It works perfectly when running on my local machine using the `meteor` command, but when I do a `meteor build` and deploy that to my server, it doesn't work anymore. I have left my console.logs in my code to show you where it breaks.

HTML Form:

```
<form id="contactForm">
    Name:
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="words">
    Email:
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    Message:
    <textarea id="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Client Code:

```
 Template.contact.events({
    'submit form#contactForm':function(e){
      console.log("Submit Button Clicked");
      var name = e.target.name.value;
      var email = e.target.email.value;
      var message = e.target.message.value;
      var namel = name.length;
      var emaill = email.length;
      var messagel = message.length;

    if(namel > 0 && emaill > 0 && messagel > 0){
      var text = "Message from: " + name + " \rEmail: " + email + "\rContent:" + message;
      Meteor.call('sendEmail', text);
      console.log("Just called sendEmail method");
      alert('Message sent! Thank you', 'success');
    }else{
       console.log("Not all fields were filled out, and the form wasn't submitted.");
      alert('An error occurred. Please make sure you have filled in all the fields.', 'error');
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Server Code:

```
 'sendEmail': function (text) {
    this.unblock();
    Email.send({
      to: 'email@test.com',
      from: 'anotheremail@test.com',
      subject: 'Form Submission',
      text: text
    });
  }
```

When I submit the form and leave a field blank, it will log all `console.log` messages. But If I submit all parts of the form, it only logs "Submit Button Clicked". I know the `IF` statement works on because it alerts properly in the webpage. I also know the server method works just fine because I can call it from anywhere else. It also works if I call it in the `else` of the Client code. It also captures the data correctly from the form because I can `console.log` those variables and they show up correctly. I'm just really confused as to why this works perfectly in my local but doesn't work at all on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it last night. The default action on an HTML form is to refresh after submission and that would break the code. Why it worked on my local machine and not when I deployed is beyond me. But instead I just cleared out the fields of the form. Here is what I did to make it work.

Client Code:

```
 Template.contact.events({
    'submit form#contactForm':function(e){
      console.log("Submit Button Clicked");
      var name = e.target.name.value;
      var email = e.target.email.value;
      var message = e.target.message.value;
      var namel = name.length;
      var emaill = email.length;
      var messagel = message.length;

    if(namel > 0 && emaill > 0 && messagel > 0){
      var text = "Message from: " + name + " \rEmail: " + email + "\rContent:" + message;
      Meteor.call('sendEmail', text);
      console.log("Just called sendEmail method");
      alert('Message sent! Thank you', 'success');
      e.currentTarget.reset();
      return false;
    }else{
       console.log("Not all fields were filled out, and the form wasn't submitted.");
      alert('An error occurred. Please make sure you have filled in all the fields.', 'error');
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```